# Add shared library to makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I want to link a shared library  `libfoo.so`,and its relative path is `../path/to/lib`.following compile command:

```
g++ -o /executable/path test.o -L../path/to/lib -lfoo
```

gives

```
/usr/bin/ld: can not find -lfoo
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and this command gives a different error message

```
g++ -o /executable/path test.o -L../path/to/lib/libfoo.so
```

gives

```
undefined reference to 'functions and class members in libfoo.so'
```

It seems neither compiles right.Did I miss something?

Comment: If you add the line `@echo $(wildcard ../path/to/lib/*)` immediately above your compile command in the `Makefile` does it print the name of your library?

Comment: @Galik Yes,it can prints the name of the library.In fact the second command did find that library,but seems not link right I think.

Comment: @Galik It prints the lib name with relative path `../path/to/lib/libfoo.so` with `@echo $(wildcard ../path/to/lib/*)` command

Comment: It seems as a linker problem. Did you install your library? Try running  ldconfig "directory_to_your_shared_libraries

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim I did't install it, I just compiled and place it in the path.

Comment: @maidamai you need to install it using ldconfig. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the library is not installed properly. I don't know which dist. are you using but these steps should do the trick.

run this command to see where your library is.

```
find / -name 'libfoo.so.*'
```

Add this to  /etc/ld.so.conf . It contains the default directories searched for libraries.

```
include /usr/local/lib
include /usr
```

To install or update run this command.

```
ldconfig
```

Good luck...

**Edit1:** Try running `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib lfoo`

**Edit2:** Run this command, but it will set only for once.

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/`

By the way, You need to run ldconfig everytime you update the library.

Comment: I know the path of the lib, as mentioned in the question `../path/to/lib`， and I compile it with `-L` option,It should find it.The second command did find the lib.

Comment: @maidamai Does your LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to include directories that will be searched? Have a look at my edit1.

Comment: I think LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used at run time not link time，and I didt set it

Comment: @maidamai Please have a look at Edit2